# Not use regex to parse html

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

While [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574585/797495) a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574464/web-scraping-photo-in-php) I found myself struggling **not** to use a [regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/797495).

How should I get the `url` value of `style="background:url(http...)` using **only** an html parser?

```
<a href="http://goruzont.blogspot.com/2017/04/blog-post_6440.html" style="background:url(https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6vpIH5iqPYs/WPzlNdxsRpI/AAAAAAAAntU/d7U_Ch_6FiIPwosNL4tWwqBeXw8qwo2nACLcB/s1600/1424051.jpg) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover">
```

To make it clear, I need:

```
https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6vpIH5iqPYs/WPzlNdxsRpI/AAAAAAAAntU/d7U_Ch_6FiIPwosNL4tWwqBeXw8qwo2nACLcB/s1600/1424051.jpg
```

Comment: [Check this out.](http://htmlparsing.com/php.html)

Comment: What specifically should I check there that answers the question?

Comment: It's titled _How to parse HTML the right way, without regular expressions_.  A helpful pointer perhaps.

Comment: Do not lead to absurdity :). This phrase is in the context of html search. Parsing value of `style` by regex is quite correct

Comment: @splash58 Could please answer the question using only an html parser? It's a challenge for me!

Comment: Of course. i can use string functions of Xpath to crop the string but think it will be slow

Comment: @Rahul I know ( and can always learn more)  *How to parse HTML the right way* , but that article doesn't address the problem in my question.

Comment: https://eval.in/781300

Comment: Is this fake question to push the idea of not parsing html with regex ? Absurd !! Just take off the regex tag, and all references to regex in your question. Html parsers _use_ regex to parse tags. Has nothing to do with nested content. `<(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</\1\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>`

Comment: The question is legit. Sure they do, but the majority of dom parsers coders know what they're doing, not like a lot of people... It's completely different to use an html parser based on regex than using regex to parse html. Don't take this too personally ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without regex:

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('
<a href="http://goruzont.blogspot.com/2017/04/blog-post_6440.html" style="background:url(https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-6vpIH5iqPYs/WPzlNdxsRpI/AAAAAAAAntU/d7U_Ch_6FiIPwosNL4tWwqBeXw8qwo2nACLcB/s1600/1424051.jpg) no-repeat center center;background-size:cover">
');
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
echo $xpath->evaluate('substring-before(substring-after(string(//a/@style), "background:url("), ")")');
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/781300)**

Comment: As you said, it's slow but it does answer the question correctly. tks!

Comment: Don't mention it :)